# Runtime Error: Corrupted Variable

Tags: c

I've been messing around with my code for awhile...and now when I run it, and in the menu, click the second option, when I put in a password above 15 characters I get this error?
Can anyone see wha I've done wrong? Its probably something small I just can't spot
Thanks

ERROR:

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'passwordCheck' was corrupted.

CODE:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>


FILE*fp; 

char *symbols = "#~!$%^&*()+=<>?/@"; // Random Symbol is generated form this list

int main(void) {

char password[4 + 4 + 2 + 2 + 1]; // 4 Upper, 4 Lower, 2 Num, 2 Symbols
int i, j=0, len=sizeof(password)-1;
int menuNum = 0;
char passwordCheck[15+1]; // for checking password length



fp = fopen("passwords.txt", "a+"); //Opens the text file to save the Passwords

srand(time(NULL));
printf("       Main Menu\n");
printf("********************************\n");
printf("\nEnter 1 to Generate a New Password: ");
printf("\n\n");
printf("Enter 2 to Check Old Passwords: ");
printf("\n\n");
printf("Enter 3 to Exit. ");
printf("\n\n");
scanf("%d", &menuNum); // Reads number

if (menuNum == 1) // If 1 is entered on the Menu...
{
    printf("********************************\n");
    printf("\nYour New Password is: \n\n");

// Each Password will Have 12 Characters(4 Uppercase letters, 4 Lowercase letters, 2 Numbers & 2 Symbols)

for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    password[j++] = 'a' + rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1); // Generates 4 random Lowercase characters 

for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    password[j++] = 'A' + rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1); // Generates 4 random Uppercase characters

for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    password[j++] = '0' + rand() % ('0' - '9' + 1); // Generates 2 random numbers

for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    password[j++] = symbols[rand() % strlen(symbols)]; // Generates 2 random symbols

password[j] = '\0';
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(password)-1; ++i)
    {
    char c = password[i];
    j = rand() % len;
    password[i] = password[j];
    password[j] = c;
    } // Shuffles passwords Characters

printf("%s\n\n", password);
printf("********************************\n");
fprintf(fp, "\n%s", password); // Outputs the Generated Passoword to the text file
fclose(fp); // Closes the text file
system("pause");
}

else if (menuNum == 2)// If 2 is entered on the Menu...
{           
    printf("\nEnter your password for checking: ");
    scanf("%s", passwordCheck);  // Reads password
    if (strlen(passwordCheck) > 15) // Checks length of Password
    {
        printf("'%s' is too long. Needs to be less then 15 Characters\n", passwordCheck);
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (strlen(passwordCheck) < 9) // Checks length of Password
    {
        printf("'%s' is too short. Needs to be more then 9 Characters\n", passwordCheck);
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: use valgrind to detect the stack corruption

Comment: Am I wrong or your password variable isn't big enough?

Comment: You should use `fscanf` instead of `scanf`

Comment: Still stuck on this if anyone can help

Answer (score 1):

You define `char password[13]`. That's good enough for 12 characters plus a null terminator.

Any attempt to index `password[13]`, `password[14]` etc. is *undefined behaviour* and the cause of your stack corruption. Similarly for `passwordCheck[]`: your `scanf` call is possibly overrunning the declared space; `strlen` will not help here as that will count merrily up to the first null terminator.

Comment: I'm still not sure what I'm supposed to change?

Comment: For starters, use `fscanf` so you only read strings *up to a certain length*. Then you will not mess up your memory.

Comment: when I change the scanf to fscanf I get an Unhandled Exception

Comment: It *will* work, eventually. It's time for you to get your debugger out!

Comment: ok I changed scanf("%s", passwordCheck); to scanf("%s", passwordCheck); I still get Unhandled Exception even after running debug

Comment: Been messing around with it for awhile, and I still can get it to work.. its when I type in a password above 15 characters..I get the output and then when i close it i get the error

Comment: Yup. `password` is not big enough to accommodate any more than 12 characters.

Comment: Could u help me fix it? I only want the passwords generated to be 12 characters... and the password check is an extra.. so when u type in a password it has to be more then 9 and less then 15

Answer (score 0):

If this condition

```
scanf("%s", passwordCheck);  // Reads password
if (strlen(passwordCheck) > 15) // Checks length of Password
```

becomes true, your memory will be already corrupted.

You should use `fgets` here.

```
 fgets(passwordCheck, sizeof passwordCheck, STDIN);
```

The only problem with this is, that if the user enters 20 characters but your password is 15 and the first 15 chars would be correct, it would identify the password as correct, even though the user enters technically a wrong password. If you want to address this as well, you would have to read the input character by character to make it safe and construction the string manually, OR you make the buffer a few chars bigger while the password still is only 15 long, then you can see if the user enters a longer string than he should, and the code would still be safe.

Comment: If I change that to fscanf I get another runtime error.. I don't understand, it was working fine

Comment: How did you use fscanf?

Comment: fscanf("%s", passwordCheck);  // Reads password
if (strlen(passwordCheck) > 15)...

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the wrong function. You should use `fgets` instead of `scanf` familiy here, because you are reading a string anyway and `fgets` allows you to limit the input, thus preventing the buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You define char passwordCheck[16],when you input 16 or >16 characetrs,passwordCheck stack out,and behind memory corrupted by your inputs.
by the way,what's your compile?gcc and vc can run your code with no error